# Spectral radius of a matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-radius

Let $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be two invertible matrices. I want to know if one can always find real scalars $\lambda_1, \ldots,\lambda_p$ such that

$$\rho\left(\prod_{i=1}^{p} (A- \lambda_i B) \right) < 1$$

where $\rho$ denotes the spectral radius.

Comment: $p$ is fixed? or I can choose as many as I want?

Comment: @Exodd p is not fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take 
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},\quad
B = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
They are simoultaneously diagonalizable and the eigenvalues of $A+\lambda B$ are $1\pm\lambda \text i$, that have both norm at least 1. Notice that the eigenvalues of
$\prod_{i=1}^{p} (A- \lambda_i B) $ are 
$\prod_{i=1}^{p} (1- \lambda_i \text i) $ and 
$\prod_{i=1}^{p} (1+ \lambda_i \text i) $, that have both norm at least 1.

Comment: @ Exodd In general if $A=diag(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ and  $B=diag(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n)$, then $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(A-\dfrac{\alpha_i}{\beta_i}B)=0$$ so the property is true in this particular case.\\ One can show similarly that the property is true when $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously trigonalizable

Comment: @DrissAlamiLouati in fact my $B$ is not diagonal

Comment: @DrissAlamiLouati you are mixing something: $B,A$ may be sim. diagonalizable even if one of the two has complex eigenvalues. Since your $\lambda$ are real, you cannot choose $\lambda=\alpha_i/\beta_i$ since they are complex numbers

Comment: @ Exodd Sorry,I misunderstood your answer. I think it's ok, thanks. I am also interested in knowing if we can give conditions on A and B so that the property is true

Comment: $AB=BA$ should work. I am also very tempted to say symmetric, but I have a strange feeling about that. @DrissAlamiLouati